# Debugging lambda locally using cdk not sam

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

AWS CDK provides great features for developers. Using CDK deveolper can manage not only total infrastructure but also security, codepipeline, ...

However I recently struggling something. I used to debug lambda using SAM for local debugging. I know how to set up CDK environment, and debug CDK application itself. But I can't figure out how to debug lambda application inside CDK.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SAM and CDK together as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/sam.html). In particular:

1. Run your AWS CDK app and create a AWS CloudFormation template

   `cdk synth --no-staging > template.yaml`
2. Find the logical ID for your
   Lambda function in template.yaml. It will look like
   MyFunction12345678, where 12345678 represents an 8-character unique
   ID that the AWS CDK generates for all resources. The line right
   after it should look like: `Type: AWS::Lambda::Function`
3. Run the function by executing:

   `sam local invoke MyFunction12345678 --no-event`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Document says lambda written by typescript is able to debug. Do you know whether lambda written by javascript is also able to debug or not?

Comment: You might need to add some more detail to your question for this. What steps have you tried and where are you getting stuck? The workflow I've described here should work exactly the same as it would without the CDK though.

In general, if you're able to debug TypeScript then you should certainly be able to debug JavaScript too.

Comment: Great answer.Thank you so much. May I want to ask another thing?
My team wants to start a service using CDK. We want to mange all infrastrucre using CDK, develop business logic using lambda. If we start using this aproach, our service's CDK code is going to really big code. I mean, there could be at least 3 stage ( dev, staging, product), And there are also front and backend and some batch style lambda code.
I wonder whether it is maintainable after launching, becuase this kind of CDK will be very large amount of code. CDK deploy command could be run very long time.
Do you have a good idea?

Comment: @Eddy, I'm not sure. My perception is that good practices around modularising CDK apps are still emerging. My instinct would be to keep everything together until you have a good reason not to. You can still create multiple stacks within the one CDK app and deploy them individually.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/stack_how_to_create_multiple_stacks.html

Answer (score 5):

As of 4/29/2021, there's an additional option for debugging CDK apps via SAM. It's in preview  but this blog post covers it : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-aws-sam-and-aws-cdk/.

Basically, install the AWS CLI and AWS CDK. The install the SAM CLI - beta, available here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-cdk-getting-started.html.

Then you can run command's like:

`sam-beta-cdk build` `sam-beta-cdk local invoke` `sam-beta-cdk local invoke start-api` and even emulate the Lambda service with `sam-beta-cdk local start-lambda`

Comment: Thank you for sharing this you changed my life.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using VSCode, you can set up a launch action to run the current file in `node` to test it locally. **All you need to do is hit F5** on the file you want to test.

You will need to add the following at the end of your handler files so that when executed in `node` the handler gets executed:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && process.argv.includes(__filename)) {
  // Exercise the Lambda handler with a mock API Gateway event object.
  handler(({
    pathParameters: {
      param1: "test",
      param2: "code",
    },
  } as unknown) as APIGatewayProxyEvent)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
      return response;
    })
    .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
}
```

Add this to your launch configurations in your `.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Current TS File",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["${relativeFile}", "-p", "${workspaceFolder}/tsconfig.json"],
      "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register", "-r", "tsconfig-paths/register", "--nolazy"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
      "smartStep": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "node_modules/**"]
    },
```

The `ts-node` and `tsconfig-paths` are only needed if using Typescript. You must add those with `npm i -D ts-node tsconfig-paths` if you dont already have them.

Comment: I struggled with a bunch of different ideas on how to get local debugging working with AWS SAM CDK, etc. and this option ended up being the simplest and making the most sense

Answer (score 0):

Before you run any of the sam local commands with a AWS CDK application, you must run **cdk synth**.

When running sam local invoke you need the function construct identifier that you want to invoke, and the path to your synthesized AWS CloudFormation template. If your application uses nested stacks, to resolve naming conflicts, you also need the stack name where the function is defined.

```
# Invoke the function FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER declared in the stack STACK_NAME
sam local invoke [OPTIONS] [STACK_NAME/FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER]

# Start all APIs declared in the AWS CDK application
sam local start-api -t ./cdk.out/CdkSamExampleStack.template.json [OPTIONS]

# Start a local endpoint that emulates AWS Lambda
sam local start-lambda -t ./cdk.out/CdkSamExampleStack.template.json [OPTIONS]
```